# CSS :after background in Safari for Windows

Tags: html, css, windows, safari

I'm trying to put some arrows onto table headers. I did this using the `:after` CSS pseudoelement.

The issue I'm facing is, this works correctly in all browsers EXCEPT Safari for Windows, where the background image just doesn't appear.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to resolve the issue?

HTML

```
<div class="test">ABC</div>
```

CSS

```
.test:after
{
    content:" ";
    background:url(http://www.designwalker.com/img/arrow/arrow06.jpg);
    padding-left:20px;
    background-size:10px 10px;
}
```

Note: this is just an example, not what it really will look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify `display: inline-block` (or `block`) and also a `height`.

```
.test:after {
  content:" ";
  background:url(http://www.designwalker.com/img/arrow/arrow06.jpg);
  padding-left:20px;
  background-size:10px 10px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/OrIdozUc/2/edit